Colossians 1:22 in the "body of His flesh" what is different between body and flesh death
Colossians 1:22 in the "body of His flesh" what is different between body's death and flesh's death. Is it same?

Good question. Up-voted +1. Please see the Tour and the Help, below, as to the purpose and functioning of the site. Please also see the archive of question-answer contributions as to how this plays out in practice. Welcome to SE-BH.

I'm having trouble understanding the question.  Is it asking whether there's a distinction between taking it as "the death of his body" and "the death of his flesh"?

The text in question needs to be considered in full to get the meaning, for the bit quoted is only four words out of a sentence that is 80 words long (in the A.V.). It's rarely a good idea to focus on such a tiny percentage of a single sentence.
The context clears matters up. Paul is speaking of Christ being "the head of the body, the church" (vs.18). This is a spiritual body, a spiritual church. The Father has made peace through the blood of the cross, with those who were once "alienated and enemies in your mind by wicked works, in the body of his flesh through death, to present you holy and unblameable and unreproveable in his sight" (vss.20-22).
It is because Christ died as a human, his blood shed in physical death being the price of redemption, that any humans can be reconciled to God. Christ died in the flesh. The blood in his flesh had to be shed, "For without the shedding of blood there is no remission of sin" (Hebrews 9:12-14 & 22).
When sinners repent and trust in what Christ did, that is the point at which they "die to sin", entering symbolically into Christ's death even though their fleshly bodies continue living as before. This is a spiritual death, for the new believer. And, just as they went down into his death, so they are raised up to newness of life (a new spiritual life) as in his resurrection. Again, that is a spiritual experience. They then become members of Christ's spiritual body, the Church.
That is why Paul goes on to say in chapter 2 of Colossians that "although I be absent from you in the flesh, yet am I with you in the spirit." He could not be bodily present (= in the flesh). Likewise when he spoke of "the body of his flesh through death", he meant Christ's bodily death (= death in the flesh). Two ways of saying the same thing.
Then Paul used the analogy of being spiritually buried with Christ in baptism, and being raised with him through faith, through the operation of God who had raised Christ from the dead:

"And you, being dead in your sins and the uncircumcision of your
flesh, hath he quickened [made alive] together with him, having
forgiven you all trespasses; Blotting out the handwriting of
ordinances that was against us, which was contrary to us, and took it
out of the way, nailing it to the cross." Colossians 2:13-14 A.V.

Paul frequently switches from the literal to the spiritual. But in the verse in question, he sticks to the literal bodily, fleshly death of Christ. Paul also frequently contrasts physical death with spiritual death, and physical resurrection with spiritual resurrection. Once the reader knows when he makes those switches, his writing becomes clearer. But in Colossians 1:22 there is no such switch.

I believe Paul is referring to the body of His flesh, being the believers who are currently filling the church, which is the body of Christ.  The church of current believers has replaced and is filling Christ's body.
Believers are effectively dead in the flesh upon the moment of belief, meaning they are no longer bound to serve sin.  They have been freed to use the remainder of their carnal lives in the flesh to serve God.  They are placed into and "complete" (Col 2:8-15) in Christ's crucified, buried, and risen in glory body (verse 24 below) at the moment of belief (1 Cor 12:13).
Colossians 1:21-24

And you, that were sometime alienated and enemies in your mind by wicked works, yet now hath he reconciled
22 In the body of his flesh through death, to present you holy and unblameable and unreproveable in his sight:
23 If ye continue in the faith grounded and settled, and be not moved away from the hope of the gospel, which ye have heard, and which was preached to every creature which is under heaven; whereof I Paul am made a minister;
24 Who now rejoice in my sufferings for you, and fill up that which is behind of the afflictions of Christ in my flesh for his body's sake, which is the church:

A believer is "holy and unblamable" now being "in Christ".  Christ's physical death paid for the unrighteousness of all sinners, but by this grace of God through having faith (Eph 2:8-9), a believer is placed into Christ and "sealed unto the day of redemption" by the Spirit (Eph 4:30).  They have been gifted the imputed righteousness of God (2 Cor 5:21).  The believers old body being 'dead', that followed the carnal desires in the flesh, now desires to follow the guidance of the Spirit in this newness of life.
2 Corinthians 5:17

Therefore if any man be in Christ, he is a new creature: old things are passed away; behold, all things are become new.

Romans 6:1-7

What shall we say then? Shall we continue in sin, that grace may abound?
2 God forbid. How shall we, that are dead to sin, live any longer therein?
3 Know ye not, that so many of us as were baptized into Jesus Christ were baptized into his death?
4 Therefore we are buried with him by baptism into death: that like as Christ was raised up from the dead by the glory of the Father, even so we also should walk in newness of life.
5 For if we have been planted together in the likeness of his death, we shall be also in the likeness of his resurrection:
6 Knowing this, that our old man is crucified with him, that the body of sin might be destroyed, that henceforth we should not serve sin.
7 For he that is dead is freed from sin.

